# teamviewer and 2 users linux

Tags: linux, desktop, remote, teamviewer

I have a linux mint machine (host machine) running team viewer for user1. After clicking alt+f2 on host machine I login another user - user2 and leave it active.

When I try to use teamviewer from remote machine to login to host machine, teamviewer says it can't?

Is there a way to login to to session one (user1) session while not "disturbing" user2.

Is there a way on linux to get desktop remotely for user1 so that user2 could use same machine at the same time without interruption. Sort of concurrent connection to the same machine like terminal server in windows, where each user can have its own Xsession
thanks for your input.

Comment: What exact error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I want to make sure I'm understanding correctly:

You'd like to use TeamViewer to enable two simultaneous and separate connections for two separate users to this machine? Or is one of the users local while the other is remote using TeamViewer?

Because TeamViewer can't automatically use multiple inbound/outbound ports, I assume only one session can be active at a time. But you might be able to get one user logged in locally (if possible) and the other remotely. But then the remote connection will probably "take control" of the local. I don't think TeamViewer is meant to allow concurrent users to the same machine; more of a "one-at-a-time" software.

A couple things that you might try - 
1) Log in locally as user 1. Switch user (don't log out) and log in as user 2. See if user 1 can use TeamViewer to control their login remotely, while User 2 controls their local session. I can't guarantee this will work though.

2) You may be able to configure TeamViewer to use a specific port for user 1, and a different port for user 2. You'll need to set that up on all 3 machines. I'm not familiar enough with Linux to assist further with that, sorry. That (in theory) would allow two concurrent connections.